# Time complexity for the 'Restore IP Addresses' problem

Tags: time-complexity, space-complexity

There's a programming problem 'Restore IP Addresses' where given a string containing only digits, restore it by returning all possible valid IP address combinations. Example, "25525511135" returns ["255.255.11.135", "255.255.111.35"].

My solution basically breaks up the string (upto 3 chars at a time) and moves to the remaining part of the string. This way we build a list of valid ip addresses using recursion. I've pasted my solution below.

If the input is number of characters (n) what would the time complexity of this solution be (with an explanation)? Also, would memoization help in this case?

```
/**
 * @param {string} s
 * @return {string[]}
 */

function isValid(s) {
  if (s.length === 0) return false;
  if (s.length > 1 && s[0] === '0') return false;
  if (s > 255) return false;
  return true;
}

function breakString(s, parts) {
  if (parts === 1 && !isValid(s)) return [];
  else if (parts === 1) return [s];

  let ret = [];

  //break into 3 pieces
  for (let i = 1 ; i <= 3 ; i++ ) {
    let part1 = s.slice(0, i);
    let part2 = s.slice(i);
    if (!isValid(part1)) continue;
    let tmp = breakString(part2, parts-1);
    if (tmp.length === 0 ) continue;
    tmp = tmp.map((str) => part1 + "." + str);
    ret = ret.concat(tmp);      
  }

  return ret;

}

var restoreIpAddresses = function(s) {
    return breakString(s, 4);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time complexity here is exponential in `s` or `parts`, whichever is smaller.

You have a recursive function, and it calls itself three times (after removing 1, 2, or 3 characters from the beginning). Thus, if $n$ is the size of $s$ and $k$ is the number of parts, your time complexity $T(n, k)$ satisfies
$$
T(n, k) = T(n-1, k-1) + T(n-2, k-1) + T(n-3, k-1)
$$
We can roughly replace this by $T(n, k) = 3 T(n-3, k-1)$ (a lower bound) which leads to
$$
T(n, k) = \min(3^{n/3}, 3^{k}).
$$

---

For IP addresses, this exponential time complexity is likely not a huge problem. It's exponential in the number of parts, but the number of parts is only $4$, so that is not huge.

However, conceptually, your solution is pretty inefficient. Notice that you are duplicating a lot of work: you might call your `breakString` function on the tail of the same string several times, in different recursive calls.

To get a more efficient algorithm, try dynamic programming instead of recursion. For instance, can you keep track of, for each prefix and possible # of parts, whether it is a valid IP address or not? What complexity would that give?

---

**NOTE:** In the above idea to try dynamic programming, I assumed that the goal was just to return one valid IP address, not return all of them. When we have to return all of them, the time complexity changes somewhat, because the time complexity is now *at least* the time it takes to output all the answers, and there could be exponentially many answers.

Specifically, the time complexity in the worst case is bounded below by the number of decompositions of `s` in the following example: let `s` be a string of length $4n$ `1`s, and let `parts` $= 2n$. Then there are at least $3^n$ decompositions: this is the number of decompositions where there is a `.` after every block of $4$ characters.

Here is an example: for $n = 2$, `11111111` into $4$ parts has the following $3^2 = 9$ decompositions:

```
1.111.1.111
1.111.11.11
1.111.111.1
11.11.1.111
11.11.11.11
11.11.111.1
111.1.1.111
111.1.11.11
111.1.111.1
```

Again, this includes only those decompositions with a `.` after every block of $4$ characters, so there are actually more than $3^n$ total. But maybe you get the idea of why it blows up exponentially.

Comment: For every position of the string (to the end of the string), what are the valid ip's it can make for each part? I think that be O(nk)

Comment: @noi.m Yes, although I just realized in my answer, I was assuming you just have to return one valid IP address, and your problem asks to return all valid IP addresses. So that is a bit more challenging, could be more than $O(nk)$ because there could be a lot of addresses (exponentially many)

Comment: I would assume the runtime complexity wouldn't change (because we store results for every {n, parts} pair). Maybe what you're saying would affect the space complexity?

Comment: @noi.m The runtime complexity changes too. Remember that runtime complexity is always higher than space complexity. It's possible in this problem there are exponentially many answers. This might happen if the input is a long list of $1$s. Then both runtime and space complexity are at least equal to the number of answers.

Comment: Could you give an example of an input that would have a lot of returns? for eg. '111111111111' would return just 1 result right? BTW, thanks for taking time out to answer in so much detail.

Comment: @noi.m For example a string of $4n$ `1`s into $2n$ parts has at least $3^n$ answers. For $n = 2$, `11111111` into $4$ parts has `1.111.1.111`, `1.111.11.11`, `1.111.111.1`, `11.11.1.111`, `11.11.11.11`, `11.11.111.1`, `111.1.1.111`, `111.1.11.11`, `111.1.111.1`. And that is actually only the ones with a `.` after every block of $4$ characters, but maybe you get the idea of why it blows up exponentially.

Comment: I added this info to my answer.